# Material TexInputLayout change color

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

i need to change the color but i dont know how to do it. Can you help me?

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/contraseña"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="440dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"

    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Contraseña"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBT3W.png)

I want to change the grey color to white.

Comment: what colour do you want to change ?

Comment: I want to change the border and the hint text to white

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Changing the border color and hintTextColor, you can use

```
app:boxStrokeColor="your color"
app:hintTextColor="your color" /*This changes the color of hint when it's collapsed 
and moved to top that's when user enters a character.*/
app:textColorHint="your color" //This is the text color of uncollapsed hint that's the default state.
```

Furthermore, if you want to create a style then this is the complete style I use which you can modify as you need.

```
<style name="TextInputLayoutAppearanceOutLined" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/HintText</item>
    <item name="helperTextTextAppearance">@style/HelperText</item>
    <item name="counterTextAppearance">@style/HelperText</item>

    <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_grey</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/dark_grey</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="startIconTint">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="endIconTint">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/white</item>

    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">10dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">10dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">10dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">10dp</item>

    <item name="boxStrokeWidthFocused">2dp</item>


    <item name="hintEnabled">true</item>
    <!--<item name="hintAnimationEnabled">true</item>-->

</style>
```

These are the style elements to change HelperText or HintText apperance:

```
<style name="HintText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>

<style name="HelperText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.HelperText">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

And set it to `TextInputlayout` as `style="@style/TextInputLayoutAppearanceOutLined"`. Whatever mentioned in the style, you can use it in XML layout tag as well.

Also, the official docs of Material `TextInputLayout` are very important and easy to understand unlike the developer docs of Android and you should read them once to know more about it [here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields/).

Comment: Really thanks! It works

Comment: @Jorge I'm glad it helped.